# Coffescript doesnt point correct element

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Hi I have a coffeescript code like this:

```
$(document).on 'keyup', '.content_length', ->
$(this).nextAll('div.char_counter:first').text(255 - $(this).val().length);
```

Which supposed to make this code, works:

```
<div class="create_comment" >
  <%= form_for(announcement.comments.create, url: announcement_comments_path(announcement.id) ) do |form| %>
    <%= form.label :author, "Autor:" %>
    <%= form.text_field :author, class: "form-control" %>

    <%= form.label :content, "Treść:" %>
    <%= form.text_field :content, class: "form-control content_length" %>
    <div class="char_counter">255</div>
    <%= form.submit "Dodaj!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Which is part of an  which are created by the loop. The code with out `(this).nextAll` is working great, but it changes walue of all char_counter divs. So my intuition tells me that there is something wrong with pointing right div.

**EDIT:**

I think I know where the problem is. "this" refers to the input element, which is nested in a div. And I try to select a div which is sibling to a div in which the input file is located.

```
            <div class="create_comment" >
                    <form class="new_comment" .../>
                                <div class="field_with_errors"><label for="comment_author">Autor:</label></div>
                                <div class="field_with_errors"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="comment[author]" id="comment_author" /></div>

                                <div class="field_with_errors"><label for="comment_content">Treść:</label></div>
                                <div class="field_with_errors"><input class="form-control content_length" type="text" name="comment[content]" id="comment_content" /></div>
                                <div class="char_counter">255</div>
                                <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Dodaj!" class="btn btn-primary" />

</form>         </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your html,
`.content_length` is inside `.field_with_errors`, so
I think you must first get the parent and then do next, like shown below:

```
$(document).on 'keyup', '.content_length', ->
  $(this).parent().next('.char_counter').text(255 - $(this).val().length);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).on 'keyup', '.content_length', ->
  $(@).closest('div.char_counter:first').text(255 - $(@).val().length)
  return
```

Answer (score -1):

CoffeeScript is space sensitive, indent line `$(this).nextAll('div.char_counter:first').text(255 - $(this).val().length)` like this:

```
$(document).on 'keyup', '.content_length', ->
  $(this).find('div.char_counter:first').text(255 - $(this).val().length)
```

or go with inline version

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.content_length', -> $(this).find('div.char_counter:first').text(255 - $(this).val().length))
```

Also in CS you don't need `;` after statements and maybe change `nextAll()` to `find()` or `closest()` as other answer suggested.

**Edit:**

After better reading you should change
`$(this).nextAll('div.char_counter:first').text(255 - $(this).val().length)`

to:

`$('.char_counter').text(255 - $(this).val().length)`,

if there aren't other members of `.char_counter` class, or change it to ID and be done with it :)

Comment: Missing return leads to returning the `$(this)`block in the function, `this` would be `@`in coffee,...

Comment: It just looked to me that OP missed indentation. And returning or not returning in this case, in my opinion, is matter of taste (same as `@` or `this`). Correct me if I'm wrong but your solution will work with or without explicit `return`, it's CS design decision to do implicit returning and in 95% of cases it doesn't matter because most of scripting functions are important because of sideffects.

Comment: Not adding an empty return, thus avoiding implicitly returns is not only a bad habit, but can lead to serious memory issues, on node, but also in the browser.
http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/why-i-hate-implicit-return-in-coffeescript.html